# Battery charging current of simple inverter lead acid battery

Tags: battery-charging

I want to know that what is the maximum charging current of any simple inverter connected to a lead acid battery. Just like 150 ah lead acid battery.  What happening if 25 amps of charging current is flowing to a battery by solar pv module with a solar charger controller.

Comment: Have you read: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_the_lead_acid_battery  ? You cannot "just" put 25 A in a lead Acid Battery. Lead Acid batteries must be charged to a certain **voltage**, usually 13.8 V for a 12 V battery. You should make sure the voltage coming from the charger  is 13.8 V with a maximum current of 25 A, the battery will than take up to 25 A of current untill it reaches 13.8 V, then charging stops.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie 13.8v is a limit for float charging, cyclic (time limited) charging will tolerate a higher voltage, which varies with chemistry (flooded cell, gel cell). You have too simplistic a view of lead acid charging to be dishing out incorrect blanket advice. You are correct about battery university though!

Comment: Simplistic, sure, but I don't want to drown a newbee in too many details but instead give simple advise how to at least **safely** charge the battery without damaging it. I hope that you agree that my 13.8 V is at least safe for 90% of the cases. Not optimal but safe.

Comment: I have no problem with safe advice, I have a problem with saying things that aren't true, and so losing the confidence of readers. I've modified my reply to add a tl:dr which I think will satisfy both of us.

Answer (score 2):

**TL:DR** if you have the battery data sheet, respect that. If you don't, then limit yourself to C/10 current and 13.8v charging voltage.

The maximum charging current for a lead acid will be given in the data sheet. Some batteries are more robust than others. If you don't have the data sheet, then C/10 should be reasonably safe, in your case, 15A.

When charging, you need to be aware of the voltage. Sealed cells should not be allowed to exceed 13.8v on a continuous charge, and this upper voltage will be safe for all types. If you have the data sheet for the battery, and you want maximum charge storage, then some battery versions may permit a higher voltage for a limited time, if they are in cyclic use. Because wet cells can be topped up with distilled water, the upper charging times and voltage limits are much more tolerant.